# Вывести все строки, не начинающиеся на решетку #

Tags: python, текст

Пишу программу для вывода хостов. Чтобы программа открывала файл и показывала только хосты без комментариев. Пробовал делать путем среза символом. Как сделать так, чтобы программа не выводила строки, которые начинаются с решетки

```
with open ('hostsfile', 'r') as h:
  hosts = h.read()
print(hosts[802:10000])
```

Comment: читайте строку за строкой, каждую строку проверяйте на первый символ и решайте, выводить или нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно считывать каждую строку, и ее проверять либо через первый символ, либо через `startswith()`

Содержимое `file.txt`:

```
127.0.0.1
# 111.11.11.1
133.11.12.1
# 1.1.1.1
# 255.255.0.1
```

Код:

```py
COMMENT = "#"
with open("file.txt") as file_obj:
  for row in file_obj.readlines():
    if not row.startswith(COMMENT):
      print(row.strip())
```

Вывод:

```
127.0.0.1
133.11.12.1
```